# How should UIFileSharingEnabled key appear in Info.plist

Tags: ios, app-store, application-loader

How should this key look in the Info.plist?  Below are the 4 ways i have tried it but all are rejected by Application Loader with `ERROR ITMS-90039: "Type Mismatch. The value for the Info.plist key UIFileSharingEnabled is not of the required type for that key."` This is a boolean key and i have others that look like this first one below.

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<string>true</string>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<string>YES</string>

<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<YES/>
```

Comment: My app has the 2nd one.

Comment: That was it, thank you @rmaddy.